# Character encoding works locally not live

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding, http-headers, content-type

I am returning some data from the database which is entered using many different methods, usually copied and pasted from word.

Rather than attempt to manually HtmlEncode every last character I had the bright idea to use the content-type on the page to load a different character set. Currently I am not doing anything to overwrite any default content-type. If I ran locally, the content-type was shown as utf-8 and the "foreign" characters appeared. When uploaded, the content-type was coming back as ISO-8859-1 and "foreign" characters were appearing as question marks (of two varieties...).

I then overwrote the character set returned using `Response.Charset = "utf-8";` and despite the response headers correctly showing utf-8, I am still getting question marks in place of the correct characters. Please see the images below:

**Local Page**

[image: Local page, all characters appearing correctly]

**Local Page Header**

[image: Local page header]

**External Page (notice two types of question mark)**

[image: External page, notice two types of error question marks]

**External Page Header**

[image: External page header]

I've followed http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html but apart from needing UTF-8 I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Is there a meta content-type element on the page?

Comment: Yep, set to be the same utf-8.

Comment: What does the browser show the codepage as?

Comment: Sorry could you expand slightly, do you mean what does the source code look like? If so it has the same question marks and question mark diamonds within the source code.

Comment: I mean what does the browser interpret the page as - you change the encoding in the browser and see what happens (you should also be able to see what the browser is _currently_ using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Still not sure entirely how everything's working but I'll explain what I did.

Despite headers saying the content-type was UTF-8, this didn't solve the issue. As hinted at by Oded, I found in IIS > .Net Globalisation two settings (Requests and Responses) which were set to ISO-8859-1.

Changing these to UTF-8 solved the trick.

As for why, I'm not sure, as the headers seem to be the same, so if anyone could explain what's happening that would be brilliant.